# Program to set a priority order between processes for uploading data on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet, bandwidth, uploader, processes

Several processes are uploading data. I am looking for a program that allows me to set a priority order between processes for uploading data on Windows 10. E.g., processing1.exe get 90%  of the bandwidth regardless of the other processes. Any license or price is fine.

[image]

My laptop model: MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH.

Comment: What's the laptops model? Some manufacturers provide apps that have that capability.

Comment: @Destroy666 MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH. Thanks!

Comment: Smart priority in this software could be related: https://msi.com/Landing/MSI-Center But I don't have MSI to check if that also affects networking. If not then Killer Control Center seems to be the way to go, or it just seems more suitable in general, as it's purely made for network modelling.

Comment: A similar question was posted some years ago on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/q/464441/68215